# What is the effective way to assign json value coming from MVC 4 controller action

Tags: javascript, controller, action

in view somewhere I need to assign value from action which returns json object I would like to assign like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jsonFromAction = @Html.Action("GetMenuJson", "Test");                                            
</script>
```

My Controller Action Code is below:

```
public ActionResult GetMenuJson(int? subCategoryId)
{
   _lCatService = new LeftCategoryService();
   List<FlatObject> flatObjects = _lCatService.GetCategory(UIUtility.Uitlity.CurrentLanguageCode);
   return Json(GetList(flatObjects, 0), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: make it JsonResult, ActionResult wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: 'GetMenuJson',
            data: "Test",
            success: function (result) {
                 var jsonFromAction = result;
            }
          });
```

and your api's return type should be `Json` (`JsonResult`), so that it can return the `Json`

Comment: Thanks Ashok for a quick response. It was helpful for me. but my requirement is little different I don't want any ajax call after page loaded, I just want to register some java script variable with pre defined json object on any action result..

Comment: I got the alternative way to do it by returning JavaScript action result from controller method.